# How can I show a placeholder if there are two characters?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How can I show a placeholder "Enter Your Phone Number" if the input has two characters "+1"?

Example without a placeholder:

[image]

I'm using the "react-phone-input-2" library where I choose the "countryCodeEditable" option to not remove the country code.

```
 <PhoneInput
    country={'us'}
    value={this.state.phone}
    onChange={phone => this.setState({ phone })}
    countryCodeEditable={false}
    name={"phone"}
    placeholder={"Enter Your Phone Number"}
   />
```

Comment: Placeholder for what?

Comment: @Dejan.S I need to show a placeholder if Input already has two characters

Comment: But a placeholder for what, where, what should it say and how should it look?

Comment: @Dejan.S
The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of an input field (e.g. a sample value or a short description of the expected format). The short hint is displayed in the input field before the user enters a value.

I need to show the text "Enter Your Phone Number" if the input has two characters "+1"

Comment: But as you are pointing out yourself, a placeholder is a short hint before the user enters a value. While you want to show it when there IS value already. This is simply not do-able with the placeholder attribute itself. You'd have to work around it somehow to display some text over the input maybe?

Comment: @Salketer the `+1` is not inputted by the user. It is displayed by the library after choosing a country. OP wants to display country code and a placeholder in the same time

Comment: I get what a placeholder is but it wasn't clear as to when you wanted it and how. A placeholder will not be shown (nor should it) when there is user input. What you are trying to build here is not correct UX and accessibility. First off to be correct a placeholder is not a hint, a hint is something that is present all the time like a hint to how to format something. So the correct way to do this is to first have a label to the input, if you need a hint then have a hint text just above the input field but below the label.

Comment: @Dejan.S it is a hint https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/instructions/#placeholder-text But the problem with that library is that the country code is display as user input where it shouldn't be

Comment: @Konrad but it's not, "Assistive technologies, such as screen readers, do not treat placeholder text as labels".

Comment: @Dejan.S yes, labels and placeholders are not the same, placeholder is a hint, label is a name of the field

Comment: @Konrad Placeholder is not a hint. A hint is persistent to help the user with input through out the typing. Let's say you want to show a user how something should be formated and doing so with a placeholder, have you not used bad coded inputs where you have to delete everything in the input to see just how it was suppose to be, is that a hint? What you are trying to do is to change a behaviour of a element by hacking it to be something it's not. Not all components made are good, far from it. One of the most popular multiselect for one of the JS frameworks is a mess, but hey...